# Found and fix a CTD in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, crash, gaming

I've just installed Windows 11 Pro on this PC:

```
CPU AMD Ryzen 9 7950X 16-Core Processor 4.50 GHz
RAM 32,0 GB
GPU AMD Radeon RX6800 XT
```

Via Steam, I bought and installed [Microsoft Flight Simulator 40th Anniversary Edition](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1250410/Microsoft_Flight_Simulator_40th_Anniversary_Edition/).
It downloaded the mandatory update.

But it fails to run. Before the progress bar reaches about 75% it crashes to desktop without any message.

What I did so far:

- uninstalled and installed again from scratch
- in Steam, verified the integrity of the files
- tried to run MSFS in safe mode
- applied all the pending Windows Update items
- uninstalled the [AMD Adrenalin Drivers](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-win-23-4-1)
- installed again the drivers
- searched for the error in Event viewer:

```
Nome dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: FlightSimulator.exe, versione: 1.31.22.0, timestamp: 0x6409dda0
Nome del modulo che ha generato l'errore: FlightSimulator.exe, versione: 1.31.22.0, timestamp: 0x6409dda0 
Codice eccezione: 0x80000003
Offset errore 0x0000000001e0f060
ID processo che ha generato l'errore: 0x0x1980
Ora di avvio dell'applicazione che ha generato l'errore: 0x0x1D96700B99512F5
```

Translation:

```
Faulting application name: FlightSimulator.exe, version: 1.31.22.0, timestamp: 0x6409dda0
Faulting module name: FlightSimulator.exe, version: 1.31.22.0, timestamp: 0x6409dda0
Exception code: 0x80000003
Fault offset 0x0000000001e0f060
Faulting process ID: 0x0x1980
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1D96700B99512F5
```

- did some researches about the excepction 0x80000003, [this](https://forums.flightsimulator.com/t/flightsimulator-exe-application-error-0x80000003-a-breakpoint-has-been-reached/334962) for example
- tried to set the virtual memory to fixed size
- tried to set the virtual memory to automatic

For each step, the behavior is always the same. No way to load even the first menu of the game.

What else should I do in order to find the root cause of a CTD and then fix it?

Comment: @Tetsujin Just a heads up - this question is currently being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14957/107240) in regards to its on-topicness. If you feel strongly about this please weigh in on that meta :)

Comment: @Mark - Do you by chance have VBS enabled?

Comment: @Ramhound, just checked: VBS is not enabled

Comment: Windows 11 prides itself on being better for games, so perhaps you're running against some new optimization of Windows 11. Try it on Windows 10.